# Single product owner for multiple Scrum teams

Tags: scrum

Is that a common practice to have a single product owner for more than one Scrum team, or usually you have a product owner for each team (even if multiple teams work on the same product).

Thanks

Comment: How do you define a product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [product owner](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/scrum/product-owner) should be the foremost business/user base expert for the application you're building.  Each product **should** have one product owner, however this is not always the case in practice.  Sometimes, you may have 2-3 product owners if there are several people from different departments driving the project.

In any case, the product owner or owners are associated to a single product.  Therefore, if you have more than one team working on the same product, the product owner(s) will be the same for each team of said product.

Since each product should have its own product owner(s), teams working on different products **could** have different product owner(s).